# Breaking lines of TikZ pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, plain-tex

Doing a lot of pictures sequentially with TikZ, I would like a break line behavior, resulting in more uniform lines. But I couldn't.

```
 \input{tikz}
 
 \def\maxangle{30}  
 \pgfmathsetseed{7}
 \foreach \i in {red, green, blue, red!40!blue, yellow, yellow!58!blue}
 \foreach \i in {red, green, blue, red!40!blue, yellow, yellow!58!blue}
 {%
     \tikzpicture[x=0.025\hsize,line width=8pt, cap=round]
     \draw[rotate=rand*\maxangle,\i]
          (0,0) -- +(0:5)
          -- +(90:5) -- cycle;
      \endtikzpicture %  I've tried putting some glues
                      %% and penalties here, but they
                      %% haven't work well. 
                      %% Using chars as separators 
                      %% worked "better".
 }%

 
 \end
```

I have tried put some glues at end of each picture. Some results was better than others, but none with a controlled look.

How can I achieve my goals in Plain TeX? How to get sequences of pictures resembling characters broken lines?

Comment: To me, it's important too to not overfull any line (or less as a possible).

Answer (score 2):

I just used `\raggedbottem` to avoid the vbox underfull page warning and used `\hfil` to spread the tikz along each line.

[image]

```
\input{tikz}
\raggedbottom
 
 \def\maxangle{30}  
 \pgfmathsetseed{7}
 \foreach \i in {red, green, blue, red!40!blue, yellow, yellow!58!blue}
 \foreach \i in {red, green, blue, red!40!blue, yellow, yellow!58!blue}
 {%
     \tikzpicture[x=0.025\hsize,line width=8pt, cap=round]
     \draw[rotate=rand*\maxangle,\i]
          (0,0) -- +(0:5)
          -- +(90:5) -- cycle;
      \endtikzpicture %  I've tried putting some glues
                      %% and penalties here, but they
                      %% haven't work well. 
                      %% Using chars as separators 
                      %% worked "better".
\hfil
 }%

 
 \bye
```

Comment: Only \hfil (withou \raggedbottom) didn't work.  Do you have a tip about this behavior?

Comment: @DanielBandeira raggedbottom actually has no effect on the output at all it just silences the warning here as there is no vertical stretch on the page so the page is ragged in any case but wih no glue  is underfull. raggedbottom adds stretch glue at the bottom of the page allowing it to be short with no warning given.

Comment: My first try was exactly this (adding \hfil after each figure). But my output was something strange (except by the first line, all others was empty in the center). I used pdftex. Anyway... thank you!

Comment: if you run the above without `\raggdbotom` it should look more or less the same (apart from the built in randomness) @DanielBandeira